# XCODE 6.01 + iOS 8 SDK - collection view with dynamic cell sizes but without autolayout and facing issues on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, autolayout, ios8

Here is the situation -

1. Cell has two states, selected and non selected.
2. Selected state has a different height then the non selected state
3. Cell turns selected/non selected on tap
4. Each cell has a scrollview which appears at the lower bottom when the cell is selected to expand
5. Each scrollview has some images with tapgestures.
6. On tapping the images inside the scrollview -  A label shows up on the cell.

The problem -
ONLY COMING FOR IOS 7 , WORKING PERFECTLY ON IOS 8
On tapping the scrollview in the expanded cell state , the didSelectItemAtIndexPath is called if the tap area is below the original cell height.
If the tap area is inside the original cell height then the tapgesture responds perfectly.
So Half of the image view inside the scrollview (falling inside the original height) is responding to tapgesture and half of the imageview calls didSelectItemAtIndexPath (WEIRD!!)

If this is a iOS 8 Bug - Apple please fix it immediately !! Else can someone think of a solution for this , let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on *cellForItemAtIndexPath:*

```
//Workaround: Size issue of UICollectionViewCell contentView's frame, happens when running on iOS 7 only
cell.contentView.frame = c.bounds;
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```